# Is there a loading priority for login_enqueue_scripts?

Tags: plugins, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using this function to load my plugins (custom-logo-and-login) Javascript file in the footer of the login.php page, but the file loads right before the wp-includes main jQuery library:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'login_js_script' );
function login_js_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'login-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'scripts.js', null, null, true );
}
```

How can I force the priority or loading after the main jQuery file? I can't find a way to add a priority. Do I need to unenqueue the main library and enqueue it later than my file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load it after jQuery, you can use script dependency... (3rd param)

For example if your scripts depends on jQuery, you can use:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'login-script', 
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'scripts.js', 
    array( 'jquery' ),
    null,
    true
);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it was that simple :)